# How to send a "button is pressed signal" to a higher class in widget tree hierarchy in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In my app tree hierarchy, I have a Stateful widget that represents the elements of a list. Let's call this class **Item**. This Widget contains an Image, some text, and a remove button that should remove the element when it's pressed. Later in the code, I have another Stateful class that holds the **ListView** and a List of **Item** which the ListView is created based on it.
My problem is that the `onPressed()` attribute of every *Item* is placed inside the item's class and not the upper class (the *ListView*) in which the remove operation should be handled. How can I fix this? How can I send a signal whenever the button is pressed to the parent widget in order to initiate removing the item?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  const Item({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemState createState() => _ItemState();
}

class _ItemState extends State<Item> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(children: [
          Image(),
          Text('abc'),
          Text('abc'),
          Text('abc'),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: ????? , child: Text('RemoveButton'))
        ],),
    );
  }
}


class ListOfItems extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListOfItems({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListOfItemsState createState() => _ListOfItemsState();
}

class _ListOfItemsState extends State<ListOfItems> {

  List<Item> ls = [];
  int numOfItems = 0;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(children: ls,)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please select the answer as accepted if it worked for you

Comment: @kzrfaisal I haven't yet tested it.  I'll accept it after that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(dynamic data) onPressedHandler;
  const Item({ @required this.onPressedHandler, Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemState createState() => _ItemState();
}

class _ItemState extends State<Item> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(children: [
          Image(),
          Text('abc'),
          Text('abc'),
          Text('abc'),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
            final data = 'Any additional data you want to paas';
            widget.onPressedHandler(data);
          } , child: Text('RemoveButton'))
        ],),
    );
  }
}


class ListOfItems extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListOfItems({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListOfItemsState createState() => _ListOfItemsState();
}

class _ListOfItemsState extends State<ListOfItems> {

  List<Item> ls = [];

  int numOfItems = 0;

  onPressedHandler(data) {

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(children: [
      Item(onPressedHandler: onPressedHandler),
    ],);
  }
}
```